# Analytics code for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

I have implemented the e-commerce tracking of analytics with magento but now I want to add to my analytics the Site Speed Rate. If I put the code of site speed rate in the header of the site i have two trackings and if I remove analytics from magento I don't have any e-commerce tracking.

Someone can tell me how can I do it?

Comment: can you share code - how you're adding your code?